# Is there an alternative to tidyr::unnest_wider? It fails when nested list element is not a vector

Tags: r, tidyr, unnest

I have old code that used to work using `tidyr::unnest_wider()` to unnest a nested named list into their own columns; however, it no longer works. Instead I get an error saying `x$name_of_list` must be a vector, not a `<non-vector>` object, where my non-vector objects include `<mcpfit>` and `<patchwork/gg/ggplot>` objects. It seems like they tried to address this issue [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/810), but it still doesn't work using tidyr v. 1.3.0.

I couldn't easily create a reproducible example from my own use case. But I'll use the example listed in the Github issue link above in hopes that this will work for my use case as well.

```
library(tidyverse)  
  
m <- 
  tibble::as_tibble(mtcars[1,]) %>% 
  mutate(ls_col=list(
    list(
      a=c(1:10), 
      b=lm(cyl~gear))
    )
  )  

m2 <-
  m %>% 
  unnest_wider(ls_col)
```

I am looking for EITHER an alternative `data.table` or base R solution OR a `tidyverse` workaround (e.g., remove the non-vector objects from the nested list and then use `tidyr::unnest_wider()`). `tidyr::unnest()` seems to work, but then I don't know how to pivot the column containing the lists into their own columns (R crashes every time I try something like this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify `strict = TRUE`.

```r
library(tidyverse)  

m <- tibble::as_tibble(mtcars[1,]) %>% 
  mutate(ls_col= list(
    list(
      a=c(1:10), 
      b=lm(cyl~gear))
  ))

m %>% 
  unnest_wider(ls_col, strict = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 13
#>     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb a      b    
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list> <lis>
#> 1    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 <int>  <lm>
```

---

**Why?**

The `strict` argument defaults to `FALSE`, and in this state, `unnest_wider` will convert zero-length typed objects like `numeric()` or `character()` in your list to `NA`, which can be helpful in converting lists with zero-length items into a typed column, for example:

```r
m <- tibble(ls_col = list(list(a = character()), list(a = 1))) 

m %>% unnest_wider(ls_col, strict = FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>       a
#>   <dbl>
#> 1    NA
#> 2     1
```

Whereas with `strict = TRUE`, type is strictly preserved, which means in this case we end up with a list column:

```r
m %>% unnest_wider(ls_col, strict = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   a        
#>   <list>   
#> 1 <chr [0]>
#> 2 <dbl [1]>
```

The default `strict = FALSE` can come in handy in some circumstances, since it can help rearranging complex lists with some empty items (as in parsing certain json structures). To achieve this, `unnest_wider` uses the function `vctrs::list_sizes`, (via the non-exported function `elt_to_wide`), which will throw an error if the list contains non-vector items:

```r
vctrs:::list_sizes(list(a = 1, b = lm(cyl~gear, mtcars)))
#> Error in `vctrs:::list_sizes()`:
#> ! `x$b` must be a vector, not a <lm> object.
#> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I wouldn't call this behaviour a *bug* as such, but it's a bit unintuitive and feels like we are using `strict = TRUE` for a reason other than its design rationale. However, it does work here.

<sup>Created on 2023-08-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is interesting -- do you mind expanding a bit more on what is going on with this argument?

Comment: @LMc it's a bit involved, but I've tried to sketch out the reason this works.